# CUDA CUDPP .so building

Tags: linux, cuda

I want to use CUDPP library in my project. I've downloaded sources from [project page](http://code.google.com/p/cudpp). Unfortunatly, when I ran "make", there was only static library build. I've looked into Makefile files and haven't found any dynamic lib configuration. I don't want to keep static library with the project - it's totally non-portable way.

My question is: how can I build .so dynamic library of CUDPP, without writing my own Makefile/compiling it manually? Maybe someone already did it?

**EDIT**: I've replaced "g++" with "g++ -fPIC", "gcc" with "gcc -fPIC" and "nvcc" with "nvcc -Xcompiler -fpic". When I unpack obj files from archive, and link them to shared lib, I've got no error. However, my application crashes at start, when linked with this library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you compile pass the flag `-Xcompiler -fpic` to nvcc. If you link against any cuda libraries make sure you've linked to the shared libs, otherwise you can't link it. Hopefully that's all you need.

Comment: I added these to nvcc and also -fPIC to gcc/g++. When I extract files from .a, and link them (g++ -shared *_o -o libcudpp.so), it isn't giving any error. However, when I try to run my app with this .so linked, the app crashes (gdb says, on loading this library). What did I missed?

Comment: I think you would have to recompile all the libraries in whatever static library you're using with the -Xcopmiler -fpic flag. You can't just extract them from a static library then relink them as shared, as the objects in there were never compiled with the -fpic flag. I'm pretty sure that either the sdk or some other cuda libraries already have the shared libs available (.so). If not I think you can recompile the cuda libraries from source with the -fpic flag (I haven't done this, but I believe it can be done).

Comment: I've recompiled whole cutil, which is statically linked with cudpp and the cudpp itself. I don't think I have to rebuild libcuda, cause it's already .so.

Comment: yes I don't believe you have to rebuild libcuda... its already a shared lib. Why not try linking dynamically to cudpp instead? is this too difficult? Sorry if that doesn't work I'm not sure what else I could do

Answer (score 0):

Are you also using `-shared` to create the library? You shouldn't need to extract anything from an archive if it is working correctly.

If you run `ldd` on your executable it will show you what dynamic linking is required by the app and you can check that the `-fPIC` etc. worked correctly. Also make sure that the `.so` library is on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (sorry if that's obvious, no harm in checking).

Comment: Yes, I used -shared. And application is linking to the library. I'm starting to think that something is wrong with the library itself.